# How to translate “lame duck”? Comment traduire « lame duck »?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions, politique

Dans son sens politique, on qualifie en anglais un élu de *lame duck* dans la période entre l'élection de son successeur et la passation de pouvoir :

> <sup>(*New Oxford American Dictionary*)</sup>
>   **lame duck** (noun)
>   an official (esp. the president) in the final period of office, after the election of a successor: *as a lame duck, the president had nothing to lose by approving the deal* | [as adjective] *a lame-duck governor*.

Je ne connais pas de traduction française de ce terme (et [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lame_duck) non plus). En existe-t-il ? En particulier, qu'est-ce qui est employé au Québec, qui a tendance à adopter plus rapidement les anglicismes, ou à proposer des néologismes ? Enfin, les médias de toutes régions utilisent-ils l'adjectif *lame-duck* directement, ou bien recourent-ils à des périphrases lorsqu'ils traitent de l'actualité américaine ?

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr qu'il y en ait une expression similaire. La passation de pouvoir après des élections est très rapide en France. Le sortant non réélu n'a pas le temps de poser des actes. Ceux en fin de mandats qui sentent qu'ils ne vont pas être réélu parfois en abusent (on parle d'_atmosphère de fin de règne_, mais l'idée me semble différente). On parle, au moins en Belgique où la situation est commune, d'un _gouvernement gérant les affaires courantes_ pour un gouvernement démissionnaire non encore remplacé. L'expression sonne comme un terme technique (ce qu'elle est vraisemblablement).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Je ne crois pas qu'il existe de traduction parfaite, en cela que le concept est assez lié à un contexte culturel auquel les Français (à défaut d'autres francophones) ne sont pas particulièrement habitués : les passations de pouvoir sous la V<sup>e</sup> République se font généralement une dizaine de jours seulement après les résultats. Dans ces conditions, il n'y a guère le temps pour l'ancien président de paraître "affaibli" politiquement...

Potiche a bien le sens de "lame duck", mais sera difficilement compris sans explication ("président potiche" ou quelque chose de cet ordre, sera déjà un peu plus clair).

Dans la situation équivalente, en France (et probablement pour désigner l'équivalent US), on parlera de "président sortant", ce qui me semble le terme le plus proche, même s'il n'a aucune des nuances péjoratives de "lame duck".

Pour parler d'un président à fonction honorifique mais sans pouvoir réel (ce qui est un peu le cas du "lame duck" américain, mais dans un contexte plus général), on parle aussi de "président chrysanthèmes" (en référence à la [IV<sup>e</sup> République](http://www.parlons-francais.fr/inaugurer-chrysanthemes-message-12492461.html)).

Comment: Merci. Au passage, attention aux ordinaux ! (`IV<sup>e</sup> République`, sans accent)

Comment: *Président sortant* est le terme habituellement employé pour désigner les présidents non ré-élus de tout pays assurant l'intérim, USA compris ..... de toutes fonctions (PDG, Président de club, d'association ...). Les organismes ou assemblées de tutelle ne lui laisse de pouvoir que pour les "affaires courantes".

Answer (score 5):

Il me semble qu'on parle du *[sortant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sortant)*, ce qui traduit plus *incumbent* (dans le contexte d'une élection) puisqu'on l'utilise avant l'élection, et après qu'il ait été ou non réélu. Dans une telle période de transition, le gouvernement *expédie les affaires courantes*. On dit quelquefois qu'un gouvernement ou autre personne ou assemblée élue *n'a plus de légitimité* lorsque son successeur est élu, ou même dès que l'élection approche.

Je soupçonne que le concept est plus répandu aux États-Unis en raison de l'intervalle particulièrement long entre l'[élection](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89lection_pr%C3%A9sidentielle_am%C3%A9ricaine#Transition) du président et son entrée en fonction.

Answer (score 4):

La traduction littérale propose "canard boiteux" mais la traduction est a éviter et ne sera pas comprise.

En revanche, je pense que le terme "potiche" est plus adapté.

> sens figuré : Personne ayant un rôle de représentation mais sans pouvoir réel

Même si on peut être une potiche tout le long de son mandat :P

Comment: Merci pour la proposition. J'ai peur que *potiche* ne soit pas compris hors contexte, mais le sens est proche, c'est vrai. Je cherchais plus une traduction “canonique” ou habituelle. Sur l'usage (en France et ailleurs) et les périphrases possibles, tu as des infos ?

Comment: @F'x dans le cadre politique, mais c'est vrai que ça reste assez peu usité dans le cadre formel (il faut éviter d'être insultant envers la personne). J'ai du mal a trouvé une version plus soutenue, mais sinon "C'est un président sans réel pouvoir maintenant" reste une périphrase utilisable facilement.

Comment: Potiche est [renseigné comme traduction](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/lame%20duck), en tous cas.

Comment: _Potiche_ est pour moi plus large que _lame duck_ tel qu'expliqué dans la question.  _On craignait qu'après son élection, Dmitri Medvedev soit un président potiche et que Vladimir Poutine garde le pouvoir effectif._

Comment: @Unfrancophone c'est toute l'essence de ma remarque (dernière phrase)

Answer (score 2):

Pourquoi pas utiliser « *déchu* » ?

Comment: Mérite d'être noté... mais probablement beaucoup trop fort pour la plupart des cas.